# How do i open a new window in safari when a safari is already opened

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, safari6

I need to open a new window in safari when a safari is already opened using apple script.

Note: Without use File Menu or Shortcut key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document
end tell
```